# How do I install Adobe Acrobat Pro From Web Premium CS4?

Tags: wine, adobe, winetricks

I am running the Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2, and am looking to install *Adobe Acrobat Pro* from my *CS4 Web Premium* CD. Whenever I try and install the `setup.exe` I get the following error:

```
Internal Error - invalid parameters recieved.
```

in a Wine Program Crash box.

I am running wine 1.5 and have tried 1.4 also. I have used *winetricks* and *PlayOnLinux*, and cannot get it to install with either program

Also if I can't get it installed does anyone know any programs that can link PDF files to MySql databases in Linux? I really need this to be able to host some web forms for work.

Comment: http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=847

Comment: Your second question about the PDF files should be asked separately.

Answer (score -1):

All Linux Distros can't run Windows executable program.  Booth have different application environments.

If you want to run Windows apps you could use Windows. but fortunately there are some like virtual runtime which able to run Windows apps in Linux, they are WineHQ and CrossOver